# How would I get recorded calls by phone number on twilio?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade, twilio-php, twilio-api

I was wondering how I would go about getting all the recordings for a specific phone number. So say I click the page with phone number 423-1234-1323 and I want to be able to list all the recordings on that page and play them from that page. How would I do that. I am able to get every single recording but not just the ones I want.

$recordings = $client->account->recordings;

foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array( 'From' => $phoneNumber )) as $call) {

$recordings = $call->recordings;

$recordings = $recordings->client->last_response->calls;

dd($recordings); return $recordings; }

-The return is

Services_Twilio_AutoPagingIterator

{#696 ▼

```
#generator: array:2 [▶]
#args: null
#items: array:9 [▼
```

0 => Services_Twilio_Rest_Recording

{#704 ▼

```
#subresources: array:1 [▶]
```

+"client": Services_Twilio

{#643}

+"sid": ""

+"account_sid": ""

+"call_sid": ""

+"duration": "9"

+"date_created": ""

+"api_version": "2010-04-01"

+"date_updated": ""

+"status": "completed"

+"source": null

+"channels": 1

+"price": "-0.00250"

+"price_unit": "USD"

+"uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts//Recordings/R"

}

1 => Services_Twilio_Rest_Recording {#706 ▶}

}

These recordings are for everyone not just for the number I want. Even though in the code i pass it $phoneNumber to filter through but that does nothing to filter it.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code, and give us an example of input and output, as well as an explanation of what you expect as the output.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want the outcome to be if I click on phone number 1 that all recordings that were recorded through number 1 will show up same thing if I were to click on phone number 2

Comment: You should edit your question and add the relevant info there.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [`CallSid` of the recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) against the [`PhoneNumberSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) for the number you wish to filter by.

```
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$token = "your_auth_token"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of recordings and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->recordings->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "CallSid>" => // is in list of Calls for a given phone number.
    )) as $recording
) {
    echo $recording->call_sid;
}
```